# Change size/styles of Zoom Window

Tags: magento-1.9, zoom

I need to change the size of the ZoomWindow and make a couple style tweaks (border, cursor, etc..) I see this info is all coming from the /js/lib/elevatezoom js files so do I just edit the non-minified version, then re-minify it? Or is there a more 'proper' way to work with these js files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best would be to use css. Assuming you're using default RWD theme as elevate zoom is availiable in RWD theme only (i think :), edit proper classes in scss/module/_catalog-products.scss. those clasess are contained in .product-im-box class. Or edit styles.css (the same classes) if sass is not your thing.